# Number of planar graphs within $K_n$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $\mathcal{N}$ be collection $n$ points in the plane. The question is rather simple:

> How many planar graphs $G$ are there such that the vertices of $G$ are all in $\mathcal{N}$? (all edges must be straight and no loops are allowed)

I know this is ambiguous, but what I am looking for are useful references for anything like upper/lower bounds, related results, special cases, characterisations of such graphs etc.

I would greately appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like it may depend on how the points in $\mathcal N$ are arranged. If they're arranged in a square, for instance, then $K_4$ on those points isn't planar. Is this the case?

Comment: ... or put another way, what counts as distinct planar graph here?  What would be your answer for $n=3$? $4$ or $8$ or something else?

Comment: @Arthur no rules mentioned here that the edges have to be straight.

Comment: @Joffan That's fair, I guess.

Comment: @Arthur there's a secondary question there I guess - Is the $K_4$ different depending on which diagonal goes inside the cycle and which outside? That way madness lies...

Comment: I edited in the fact that all edges must be straight and loops are not allowed. Indeed, the result depends on how the points are arranged, but I was hoping thsi would be a somewhat known problem, with some of the particular cases already solved, such as a convex $n$-gon. And yes, it counts wether we trace one diagonal of the $K_4$ or the other. The points are fixed so even if two configurations would be equivalent via rotations or symmetries, we count them as different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference (Sharir and Sheffer) which deals with the maximal number of triangualations (as a corollary, maximum number of planar graphs) in a configuration of n points in the plane:
http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/EJC/Volume_18/PDF/v18i1p70.pdf
Many relevant references within.

Comment: Thank you. It is useful.